# Puzzling 'conductor' in a bathroom scale

Tags: components, lcd

Hoping to scavenge the LCD from an old bathroom scale for another project, I took it apart. There were four sensors -- one in each 'foot' of the scale -- all wired to a small circuit board whose back half is shown below, with the neat line of traces near the top. Sitting atop these was the small, rubbery rectangle that you see here, with its long thin edge touching the traces, and its other edge touching the LCD glass. [image] If you look closely above the jaws of the crescent wrench, you can see some milky-grayish rectangles on the LCD; those are where the other long thin edge of the rubber piece was sitting, and I assume they are the 'connections' for the LCD.

I'm therefore guessing that this rubber thing is somehow connecting the board-traces to the gray "traces" on the LCD. Can this be true? Is this a standard electronic part? I can't see any wires embedded in the rubber (but my eyes aren't great), and the alignment of the parts was maintained by what seemed like a somewhat sloppy and loose plastic assembly, which seems to belie the idea of tiny wires making the connection.

Can anyone explain?

(I've abandoned the idea of using this LCD, obviously, but I wish I could find something comparable, one with **pins** I can attach to...even AliExpress hasn't helped; It's the large size of the display that I need!)

Comment: To use the LCD you can provide connector pads matching those on the LCD and then use the zebra Strip to connect your circuit against the lCD connector with suitale pressure,

Comment: Thanks, both of you; and thanks, JRE, for that pointer, which is filled with fascinating stuff. I guess connector technology has moved on since I last really paid attention (i.e., the 1970s!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rubber strip is known as a zebra or elastomeric connector. It has alternating strips of insulating plastic and carbon-impregnated conducting plastic arranged in vertical stripes along the width of the piece in the photo. The pitch of the stripes is finer than the PCB pad spacing so that alignment is not too critical.

[image]

*Figure 1. LCD stack-up. Image source: [Fujipoly](https://www.fujipoly.com/usa/products/zebra-elastomeric-connectors/).*

The LCD uses transparent conductors on one of the glass layers. These extend out to the edge of that layer which itself extends out past the edge of any components below it so that the conductors form an edge connector. Gentle pressure is applied to the stack - usually by means of a set of plastic latches - to make the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. That rubber is the conductor between the PCB and the LCD. If you look closely, there are hundreds of thin conductors in that rubber. Sometimes, the colour is different between the conductor and the isolator, and you can spot the difference easily. This picture illustrates what is inside the rubber part ([Image source](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/172657664552)):

[image: Rubber connector]

Every manufacturer makes them according to what they need in their product. However, there are plenty of different sizes available. For example, have a look at [this link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004211639479.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the rubber contains conductive paths between PCB and LCD glass.

There is a series of narrow channels so that a larger pad on PCB and glass connect via multiple conductive paths in the rubber.

The component is casually also called a zebra strip because usually the non-conductive parts are white and the conductive parts are black and the bands alternate.